# View stored backups from the command line

Tags: linux, mysql

Is it possible just to **view** the current stored backups on the server from the command line using the `mysqldump` command? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a mysqldump command, the output is usually redirected to a file, like so:

```
mysqldump -ppassword database > /path/to/file
```

If you run the command this way, then you can see the current stored files simply by listing the directory where you are storing them.

Comment: Ah, okay - so there is no default directory chosen by `mysqldump` and no log of what previous `mysqldump`s have been executed

Comment: No there is no default directory where the output of mysqldump is stored.  You would normally use redirection and specify a file to write the dump to, as above.  As far asI know, there is no log of previous mysqldumps that have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

The mysqldump command is mostly use to dump the MySQL database to a .sql file. Using the Terminal (aka shell) you would use commands such as 'ls' to locate a file and 'less' to view the .sql file if that's what you are after.